# Data Validation for text and number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I would like to have a form where it asks for a user's name, phone number and email address. The name field should only contain letters, the phone number field should only contain numbers and the email field should contain '@'. The form needs to be validated using Javascript. The validation should happen when the user clicks on submit. Can someone help? Please look at my existing code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang = "en">
    <head>
<title>Contact</title>
<script src="datavalidation.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body onload="document.registration.userid.focus();">
<section>
  <h1>Contact</h1></br>
  <h2>To get in contact with us please fill out the contact form below</h2></br>
  <p>Fill in all of the boxes below and click the 'Submit' button to submit message and one of our team will get back in touch with you within 48 hours</p></br>

<form name='registration' onSubmit="return formValidation();">
  <ul>
    <li><label for="username">Name:</label></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="username" size="50" /></li>
    <li><label for="number">Phone No:</label></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="number" /></li>
    <li><label for="email">Email:</label></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="email" size="50" /></li>
    <li><label for="desc">Message:</label></li>
    <li><textarea name="desc" id="desc"></textarea></li>
    <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
  </ul>
 </form>
</section>
```

Javascript:

```
function formValidation()
 {
 var uname = document.registration.username;
 var unumber = document.registration.number;
 var uemail = document.registration.email;

 {
 if(allLetter(uname))
 {
 if(allnumeric(unumber))
 {
 if(ValidateEmail(uemail))
 }
 }
 }
 return false;

 function allLetter(uname)
 {
 var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
 if(uname.value.match(letters))
 {
 return true; 
 }
 else
 {
 alert('Username must have alphabet characters only');
 uname.focus();
 return false;
 }
 }

 function allnumeric(unumber)
 {
 var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
 if(unumber.value.match(numbers))
 {
 return true;
 }
 else
 {
 alert('Phone number must have numeric characters only');
 unumber.focus();
 return false;
 }
 }
 function ValidateEmail(uemail)
 {
 var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
 if(uemail.value.match(mailformat))
 {
 return true;
 }
else
{
 alert("You have entered an invalid email address!"); 
 return false;
} 

else
 {
alert('Form Succesfully Submitted');
window.location.reload()
return true;
}
}
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function formValidation()
{
 var uname = document.registration.username;
 var unumber = document.registration.number;
 var uemail = document.registration.email;
 
 if(allLetter(uname))
 {
  if(allnumeric(unumber))
  {
   ValidateEmail(uemail)
  }
 } 

 function allLetter(uname)
 {
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  if(uname.value.match(letters))
  {
   return true; 
  }
  else
  {
   alert('Username must have alphabet characters only');
   uname.focus();
   return false;
  }
 }

 function allnumeric(unumber)
 {
  var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
  if(unumber.value.match(numbers))
  {
   return true;
  }
  else
  {
   alert('Phone number must have numeric characters only');
   unumber.focus();
   return false;
  }
 }
 
 function ValidateEmail(uemail)
 {
  var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;  
  
  if(uemail.value.match(mailformat))
  {
   alert('Form Succesfully Submitted');
   window.location.reload();
   return true;
  }
  
  else
  {
   alert("You have entered an invalid email address!"); 
   return false;
  }  
 }
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang = "en">
    <head>
<title>Contact</title>
<script src="datavalidation.js"></script>
 </head>
    
 <body>
<section>
  <h1>Contact</h1></br>
  <h2>To get in contact with us please fill out the contact form below</h2></br>
  <p>Fill in all of the boxes below and click the 'Submit' button to submit message and one of our team will get back in touch with you within 48 hours</p></br>

<form name='registration' onSubmit="return formValidation();">
  <ul>
    <li><label for="username">Name:</label></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="username" size="50" /></li>
    <li><label for="number">Phone No:</label></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="number" /></li>
    <li><label for="email">Email:</label></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="email" size="50" /></li>
    <li><label for="desc">Message:</label></li>
    <li><textarea name="desc" id="desc"></textarea></li>
    <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
  </ul>
 </form>
</section>
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would not got amiss

Comment: I don't know where I went wrong, but thank you so much for this, it works.